# Calling powershell from C# for running SQL Script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the powershell scripts which executes sql scripts from C#.

If I run the powershell scripts from powershell command prompt it works but it doesn't work when I try to run it from C#

Here is the function I am using for running powershell scripts

```
public static void RunPowershell(string fileName, string functionName, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), fileName);
        string script = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);

        try
        {
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runspace.Open();
                PowerShell instance = PowerShell.Create();
                instance.Runspace = runspace;

                instance.AddScript(script);

                instance.Invoke();

                instance.Commands.Clear();
                var command = instance.AddCommand(functionName);
                if (null != parameters)
                {
                    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        command.AddParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                    }
                }
                var result = instance.Invoke();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

and my powershell script is(Test2.ps1):

```
    function RunScript(){
    Import-Module "SQLPS" -DisableNameChecking
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -inputfile ".\TestSQL.sql" -ServerInstance . -Verbose
}

function ShowMessage(){
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hi from Powershell !")
}
```

TestSQL.sql looks like this:

```
    USE TEST
GO
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES('1', 'abc')
```

It Shows the Message Box when I try:

```
PowershellHelper.RunPowershell("Test2.ps1", "ShowMessage", null);
```

But doesn't insert into the table when I try:

```
PowershellHelper.RunPowershell("Test2.ps1", "RunScript", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you probalby do not have the TestSQL script on your current directory. You will have to either give the fullpath or switch your current directory.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -inputfile "C:\FolderWhereYouhavetheSQL\TestSQL.sql" -ServerInstance . -Verbose
```

or

```
cd "C:\FolderWhereYouhavetheSQL"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -inputfile ".\TestSQL.sql" -ServerInstance . -Verbose
```

Comment: TestSQL.sql is in the same directory as Test2.ps1. I tried with full path but it didn't worked.

Comment: What is the output you are getting when you run Test2.ps1 seperately from powershell ?

Comment: when I run Test2.ps1 from powershell command prompt I can see the script executed properly and values getting added in the table.